# Subtract a specific column of a file from another for even lines only

Tags: awk

I have two long files that have the repeating general structure,
File1:
`AA 100`
`BB 10`
File2:
`AA 100`
`BB 1`

I want to subtract column 2 from even lines of File2 from File1, but maintain/print the other information so it remains.
Desired output:
`AA 100`
`BB 9`

For which I have written the `awk`:
`awk '{a=$2;getline<f;$2-=a}!(NR % 2)' f=File1 File2`

This produces:
`BB 9`
Which does the subtraction and prints the result fine, but I'm having trouble adding in the other data.

How can I also print the other data alongside this subtraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
awk '{a=$2;getline<f;(NR%2)?$2:$2-=a;print}' f=File1 File2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1, $2 - (NR%2 ? 0 : $4)}'
AA 100
BB 9
```

or if you wanted an awk-only solution:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (!(NR%2)) a[NR]=$2; next} {$2 -= a[FNR]} 1' file2 file1
AA 100
BB 9
```

If you were considering using `getline` for this, please read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline so you're aware of the issues around doing so.